# Is it possible to disable the access in the lock screen to the dialer and the camera?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I've updated my rooted, Nexus 5 with an OTA update to Android 5.0 Lollipop and since then I have noticed something that quite bugs me.

After the update has been added to the phone lock screen access to the camera if I slide to the right, and the dialer if I slide to the left.

I liked the old method (without any additional apps in the lock screen)

How can I disable/remove them from there?

Comment: One way is to use a custom lock screen.